# Query lead owner city in apex soql

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, ownership

I am trying to do an soql query in apex which will fetch the lead city value as well

My query is looking something like the following:

```
 select count(Id)cnt, OwnerId from Lead where Owner.City =: leadCity group by OwnerId order by count(Id)
```

However the above is not working

I have also tried the following variation:

```
 select count(Id)cnt, OwnerId from Lead where Owner.Address.City =: leadCity group by OwnerId order by count(Id)
```

LeadCity is a set which is prepopulated

Is this the correct way to query the lead owner city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to find the number of leads owned by each person in a certain area (determined by `leadCity`). If that's the case, then this query should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) cnt, OwnerId 
FROM Lead 
WHERE OwnerId IN (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE City = :leadCity) 
GROUP By OwnerId 
ORDER BY count(Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a list or a set in the `WHERE` clause, you need to use the `IN` operator and not `=`.

```
SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Owner.City IN :leadCity;
```